# Angular2/4 :Access variable declared in parent class

Tags: angularjs, angular2-forms

This might probably be a stupid question, however, when I am trying to get the value in **console.log(this.userGender),** it is undefined. I am using localStorage to get the value of userGender which I want to pass it to the form controls. I am a bit perplexed at why I am not able to access its value, when I have declared it under the parent class PersonalDetailsPage

Here is my js code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams ,Platform} from 'ionic-angular';
import { NativeStorage } from '@ionic-native/native-storage';
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, AbstractControl} from '@angular/forms';
import { CustomValidtorsProvider } from '../../providers/custom-validators/custom-validators';

@Component({
  selector: 'personal-details',
  templateUrl: 'personal-details.html',
})
export class PersonalDetailsPage {
  authForm : FormGroup;
  username : AbstractControl;
  phone : AbstractControl;
  dob : AbstractControl;
  pincode : AbstractControl;
  address : AbstractControl;
  state : AbstractControl;
  city: AbstractControl;
  gender : AbstractControl;
  email : AbstractControl;
  myDate : AbstractControl;  
 userEmail : string;
 userPhone : number;
 userDob : string;
 userAddress : string;
 userPincode : number;
 userGender : string;
 userState : string;
 userCity : string;
 userImg : any;
 userName : string;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private nativeStorage : NativeStorage, private fb : FormBuilder,
  private platform : Platform ) {
      this.nativeStorage.getItem("fbLogin").then((data)=>{
      this.userImg = data.picture;
      this.userName = data.name;
      this.userEmail = data.email;
    }).catch((c)=>{console.log(c);this.userImg = "http://icons.iconseeker.com/png/fullsize/transformers-x-vol-3/heroic-autobots-1.png"});
    this.nativeStorage.getItem("profileData").then((data)=>{   

      this.userName =  data.FullName;
      this.userEmail = data.EmailID;
      this.userPhone = data.Phone;
      this.userAddress = data.Address1;
      this.userPincode = data.PinCode;
      this.userGender= data.Gender;
      this.userDob =  data.Dob;
      this.userCity = data.City;
      this.userState = data.State;
      }).catch((c)=>{console.log(c)})


      this.authForm = fb.group({
        'username':['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
        'password':['',Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
        'phone':['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
        //'dob':['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
        'pincode':['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
        'address':['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
        'state':['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
        'city':['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
        'gender':['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
        'email':['', Validators.compose([Validators.required,CustomValidtorsProvider.EmailValidator])],
        'myDate':['',""],
      }); 
      this.username = this.authForm.controls['username'];
      this.phone = this.authForm.controls['phone'];
      //this.dob = this.authForm.controls['dob'];
      this.pincode = this.authForm.controls['pincode'];
      this.address = this.authForm.controls['address'];
      this.state = this.authForm.controls['state'];
      this.city = this.authForm.controls['city'];
      this.gender = this.authForm.controls['gender'];
      this.email = this.authForm.controls['email'];
      this.myDate = this.authForm.controls['myDate'];
      console.log(this.userGender);      
      this.authForm.controls.gender.setValue(this.userGender);
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {


  }


  onSubmit(value: string) : void{ 
    if(this.authForm.valid){
      // 
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: I would try moving this.authForm part in a separate function initForm and call that function inside then of native storage. I'm pretty sure its because form is trying to get created before the value is loaded from Native storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying synchronously to use the data loaded from an async operation: `this.nativeStorage.getItem()`.

Change your program flow as below:

```
this.platform.ready()
.then(()=> {
  return this.nativeStorage.getItem('profileData');
})
.then((data)=> {
  this.userGender = data.Gender;
  ...
  this.initializeForm(); // initialize form only after native/local storage loads all the data
});

initializeForm (){
  console.log(this.userGender); // will print value from local/native storage by this point
  this.authForm = this.fb.group({
     ...
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, would it help if I used platform.ready() and moved my code in that block?

Comment: That could be required as well, on the native devices.

Comment: @Arun- Check the updated answer and let me know how that comes.

Comment: I am getting the error "Error: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in"

Comment: So i got the problem, the from still didn't initialize I had added an *ngIf="userGender" on the form tag, this will wait for the userGender to load with values and then render the form.